# JAXB bindings - address content of an xs:string extension with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, jaxb, xjc

I want to configure *xjc* to annotate a certain attribute in a generated Java class using the *jaxb2-basics-annotate* plugin but I am struggling to address the particular XML element with *XPath*.

Here is an extract of the *xsd* (which btw, cannot be changed by myself):

```
<xs:complexType name="ExpressionType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The corresponding xjc-generated Java class looks like this:

```
....
public class ExpressionType
{

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    protected String id;

    ...
```

in the `bindings.xjb` file I'd like to configure that the Java attribute `value` gets annotated by annotation `XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, so something like this:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ExpressionType']/<???>" multiple="true">
    <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyOwnCdataAdapter.class)</annox:annotate>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The three `???` refer to my question ;-) : How to address the inner content which is mapped to Java attribute `value` in XPath?

For the `id` attribute I succeeded using

```
//xs:complexType[@name='ExpressionType']/xs:simpleContent/xs:extension/xs:attribute[@name='id']
```

but for my demands, I don't see how to express this in xpath, also reflecting that the type is an extension of `xs:string`.

Comment: Not a solution to the concrete question, but I bypassed the problem by mapping the element `ExpressionType` to a non-generated Java type using `<jxb:class>`. As I don't expect frequent changes in the XSD, especially not for this element, I can live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this issue](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/issues/24) for the solution.

I just copy-paste the solution here to avoid the "link-only" downvotes.

---

This appeared to be more complex than I thought. I did not manage to attach customizations to the simple content-derived property with standard XJC means. So I wrote the `customizations` plugin which reads customizations from files, associated with classes or fields. For instance, `org\jvnet\jaxb2_commons\tests\issues\Gh24Type.value.xml` customizes the `value` property of the `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.tests.issues.Gh24Type` class.

So how it works:

- Include `jaxb2-basics`
- Enable `-Xcustomizations` plugin and point `-Xcustomizations-directory=<dir>` to whatever directory you want to load customizations files from. For instance, `${basedir}/src/main/resources`.
- Create a file named after the class and/or property you want to customize. For instance for the `value` property of the `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.tests.issues.Gh24Type` class you'll have the `src/main/resources/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/tests/issues/Gh24Type.value.xml` file.
- Put your customizations into this file. Must be valid XML, for instance:

  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyOwnCdataAdapter.class)

See [this project](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/tree/master/tests/issues), especially `Gh24Type` for example.

The new feature has been released with version 1.0.3 of jaxb2-basics.

Hope this helps.

---

*Disclaimer:* I'm the author of the `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` as well as the solution described above.