# Problem with adding annotation for JAXB created classes

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I'm using `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to generate my models based on `.wsdl` file. Now I need to add annotation to one of the classes. I tried to use `jaxb2-basics-annotate` and was very close to succeed, but now I'm stuck.

My goal is to achieve this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BinaryObjectType", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class BinaryObjectType {

    @XmlValue
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BinaryObjectTypeValueAdapter.class)
    protected byte[] value;
}
```

but my current output is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BinaryObjectType", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BinaryObjectTypeValueAdapter.class)
public class BinaryObjectType {

    @XmlValue
    protected byte[] value;
}
```

My `bunding.xjb` looks like this:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="file:./schema.wsdl"
                  node="//xs:complexType[@name='BinaryObjectType']/xs:simpleContent">
        <annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter"
                            value="example.mapper.BinaryObjectTypeValueAdapter">
            </annox:annotate>
        </annox:annotate>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Relevant fragment of the `.wsdl`:

```
<xsd:complexType name="BinaryObjectType">
 <xsd:annotation...>
 <xsd:simpleContent>
  <xsd:extension base="xsd:base64Binary">
   <xsd:attribute name="format" type="xsd:normalizedString" use="optional">
   ...
  </xsd:extension>
 </xsd:simpleContent>
```

I cannot modify it. Basically my problem is that I don't know how to specify XPath to the `value` property of `BinaryObjectType` class. I tried to use simpleContent, extension etc., but nothing worked for me. I saw that I can specify `target` on `annox:annotate` level, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

All day googling and I found that [JAXB bindings - address content of an xs:string extension with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057887/jaxb-bindings-address-content-of-an-xsstring-extension-with-xpath). Not yet implemented, but looks like an answer.